# Oracle 10G add new record at last of all the records in table

Tags: oracle10g

I have created a table in oracle 10g.. But while inserting a record, the newly inserted records are adding in middle of the records.. I just want the newly inserted record at last of  all the records.. Is there any remedy...???

Comment: Does your table have a primary key? (hint)

Comment: This is expected behavior, it's by design. There is no "beginning" of rows, or "middle" of rows, or "end" of rows.  If you need to guarantee that rows are returned in a particular order, you absolutely MUST include an ORDER BY clause in your query.

Answer (score 3):

A heap organized table is inherently unordered.  It doesn't make sense to talk about the "first" row, the "last" row, or a row "in the middle".  Rows are rows.  It only makes sense to talk about the order of results in a query and then only if you have specified an `ORDER BY` clause.  Otherwise, it would perfectly correct for Oracle to return the results in any order, for the order to change over time, etc.

If you want to present the rows in the order they are inserted, you'll need to identify (or add) a column that provides this information.  And then you'll need to add an `ORDER BY` clause to your query, i.e.

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 ORDER BY insert_date
```